# Undoing change() in laravel 5 (data definition)

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-migrations

I am unfamiliar with what the opposite of unassigned is in Mysql, so if I did:

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    $table->int('id')->unsigned()->change();
});
```

for up, What would be the down version of that?

Comment: Why don't you just do the opposite of what you did, in your down method?

Comment: is unsigned suit for string?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need some explanation here.

There is no "change" in MySQL that you can "undo". It is just a configuration of some entity (table/field/...).

It works like this - you create a configuration of what this field needs to have and MySQL bring it to this stage.

There is also number of defaults and if you don't specify some parameter, then the default one will be used.

for example you do this

```
$table->int('id')->unsigned()->change();
```

by default the filed is nullable, so in this line of code you are making sure that the new field must be "nullable" and "unsigned".

It is impossible to say what change you are making there without knowing the previous state of the filed.

If this field was not nullable, it will become nullable. But if it was nullable then it will stay nullable.

If this field was signed, it will become unsigned. But if it was unsigned, it will stay unsigned.

Answer (score -1):

For rollback you need to use raw query to revert unsigned

```
public function down()
    {
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `users` MODIFY `id` INT(10)');
    }
```

And  i think what you mean is integer instead of string with using unsigned.

If you get `'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' not found` error when migrating , add    `"doctrine/dbal": "^2.5"` to require section of composer.json or simply run `composer require doctrine/dbal` command.